# Where can I find quartz-all-2.2.1.jar file

Tags: java, exception, jar, quartz-scheduler

I'm developing code that executes a quartz job. When I execute this code on my local tomcat it is working fine, but when I try to do the same code inside a web application I get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/quartz/DisallowConcurrentExecution. I'm using quartz 2.2.1 and it's already in the class path. Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1600)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.quartz.impl.JobDetailImpl.isConcurrentExectionDisallowed(JobDetailImpl.java:388)
    at org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore.acquireNextTriggers(RAMJobStore.java:1428)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:272)

Exception in thread "DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/quartz/DisallowConcurrentExecution
    at org.quartz.impl.JobDetailImpl.isConcurrentExectionDisallowed(JobDetailImpl.java:388)
    at org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore.acquireNextTriggers(RAMJobStore.java:1428)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:272)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.quartz.DisallowConcurrentExecution
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 3 more
```

I already read that I should check if I have multiply quartz-all-xxx.jar in my classpath and that I should use quartz-all-xxx.jar except of quartz-ver.jar.

Quartz Documentation:

> The Quartz package includes a number of jar files, located in root directory of the distribution. The main Quartz library is named quartz-all-xxx.jar (where xxx is a version number). In order to use any of Quartz's features, this jar must be located on your application's classpath.

I can't find this quartz-all-xxx.jar in the quartz package and I also tried to find it as a single file. Does anyone know a download link or if it maybe got deleted?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *I'm using quartz 2.2.1 and it's already in the class path* and *I can't find this quartz-all-xxx.jar in the quartz package and I also tried to find it as a single file* are contradictory statements. How is it on your class path?

Comment: No, there is a difference between quartz-2.2.1.jar and quartz-all-2.2.1.jar. I have the quartz-2.2.1.jar in my classpath but I need the quartz-all-2.2.1.jar.

Comment: Jar files end in `.jar` not `-jar`. Your question doesn't make a lot of sense, but I downloaded the latest version of `quartz` and `quartz-all` wasn't an option.

Comment: Just edited it.. Yes thats what I just wrote above, that I can't find the .jar despite the quartz documentation writes about it. So do you have any constructive suggestions?

Comment: Here's [quartz-all-1.5.2](http://www.findjar.com/jar/mule/dependencies/maven2/quartz/quartz-all/1.5.2/quartz-all-1.5.2.jar.html), looks like they changed the packaging because there is no "quartz-all-2" [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz/2.2.1).

Comment: Okay thanks for the information, I will try it with this version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For quart version 2.2.1 you don't have quartz-all-xxx.jar.  Refer below

Maven artifacts are available in the central Maven repository within a few hours after a new release.

As of version 2.2.0, all of the Quartz libraries are contained in the quartz-xxx.jar file (where xxx is a version number), except for the out-of-the-box jobs, which are in the quartz-jobs-xxx.jar file.

The group id is: org.quartz-scheduler. Substitute the version number you wish to use in the dependency snippets below (e.g., "2.2.0").

http://quartz-scheduler.org/downloads

Also refer pom.xml from maven